# Itertools count all combinations with tuple length being greater than or equal to value

Tags: python, tuples, combinations, python-itertools

I have some code that takes an array of players. The integers in this array represent the skill level of each player. I take all the players that meet the minimum skill level, and maximum skill level, and then try to count all possible team combinations with at least a length of 3 or greater, with no single element in the array repeating in a given tuple.

What I have so far:

```
from itertools import combinations

def countTeams(skills, minPlayers, minLevel, maxLevel):

    # Determine which skill level integers meet criteria, append to draft if valid

    draft = []
    for i in range(len(skills)):
        if skills[i] >= minLevel and skills[i] <= maxLevel:
            draft.append(skills[i])

    # If no players with the skill criteria are appended, or there are not enough players to form one team, return 0

    if len(draft) == 0 or len(draft) < minPlayers:
        return 0

    #Otherwise, if the draft list has the minimum of the number of players required to form at least one team, find all possible team combos with no repeating elements in a given tuple

    elif len(draft) >= minPlayers:
        combos = list(combinations(draft,minPlayers))
        return len(combos)

print(countTeams([12,4,6,13,5,10],3,4,10))
```

This returns **4** `[(4, 6, 5), (4, 6, 10), (4, 5, 10), (6, 5, 10)]` when in reality my goal is to have it returning **5** `[(4, 6, 5), (4, 6, 10), (4, 5, 10), (6, 5, 10), (4,5,6,10)]`, since `{4,5,6,10}` can be a team tuple possibility, because the tuple length is greater than 3 and has no repeating elements from my draft list. I know that since I use my `minPlayers` integer value to determine the length of each tuple, it does not know to select tuple length values `greater than or equal to 3` in this example. How can I achieve this? Would it have something to do with Math.min() or Math.max()? Is combinations() able to achieve my results, or do I need to utilize a different method? Appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Below should work
Team size, N vartype: int\

```
combos=[]
For n in range(N, minPlayers+1,-1):
combos.append(list(combinations(draft,n)))
```

First line creates tuple of (4,6,6,10), then next line appends the 3-lenght tuples to combo list.

Comment: I appreciate the response, however this does not account for infinite possibilities past 3. +1 will only account for tuple sizes of 4. If I were to add additional elements to the list, I'd need it to account for a larger range of possible team sizes

Answer (score 0):

You can use `comb` from the builtin `math` module instead of producing each combination explicitly and counting them. Then, just iterate over each valid team size (equal to or greater than the min).

```py
from math import comb

def count_teams(skills, min_players, min_level, max_level):
    num_skills = len([s for s in skills if min_level <= s <= max_level])
    return sum(comb(num_skills, players) for players in range(min_players, num_skills))
```

Output:

```
>>> count_teams([12, 4, 6, 13, 5, 10], 3, 4, 10)
4
>>> count_teams([12, 4, 6, 13, 5, 10], 2, 6, 15)
10
```